# Send only udpated fields instead of all the field information

Tags: integration, fields, field-update, update, object

I am integrating an external system with Salesforce and I am sending certain information to the other system from Salesforce once a record is created or updated.

I wanted to know if it is possible to send only the updated fields information instead of sending all the information when a record is updated in Salesforce. Right now I am sending the information of certain fields once the update is performed on a record of an object. But I wanted to understand if there is any way in Salesforce to monitor only the fields that are updated by the user and send only the information of those fields to the other system. Kindly let me know if it is possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [CDC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/) (Change Data Capture) to get updates only on updated fields. You could also write manual code (Apex) to create a change delta, although this might require a lot of CPU time depending on the number of fields involved.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Will check the methods that you have mentioned here in your answer.